# Rails gem with CSS and javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've got a simple rails gem (created using bundler) and I'd like to extend it by adding some CSS and javascript functionality. However, I'm unsure how to go about this and where to add the files. In particular, I need need more information on how it all fits together with the asset pipeline once it gets included in another project.

Can anyone give me the lowdown on how this works and either provide some simple examples or link to a tutorial? Literally 1 css and 1 js file is all I'm looking to include. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write the gem as an engine. This allows you to have an `app` folder in the gem just as any Rails application would have. You can add models, views, controllers, assets etc.

Once you have it set up it's quite intuitive and it's a familiar way to create a gem if you're used to creating Rails apps.

This should get you started:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/

Comment: Great stuff - just what I needed!